# undefined method `rubyforge_name=' for #<Hoe:0xa67b7e0>

Tags: rubygems

I am testing LDAP connection with gem `net-ldap-0.3.1`

It returns the following error:

```
gems/net-ldap-0.3.1# rake autotest/discover.rb

rake aborted!
undefined method `rubyforge_name=' for #<Hoe:0xa67b7e0>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/Rakefile:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/hoe-3.11.0/lib/hoe.rb:389:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/hoe-3.11.0/lib/hoe.rb:389:in `spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/Rakefile:10:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Being able to run this is necessary for Redmine LDAP authentication.

How can I get this to work?

I am running:

- RVM

  ```
  version:      "rvm 1.25.14 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
  updated:      "3 months 4 days 1 hour 48 minutes 40 seconds ago"
  path:         "/usr/local/rvm"
  ```
- Ruby

  ```
  interpreter:  "ruby"
  version:      "2.1.0p0"
  date:         "2013-12-25"
  platform:     "i686-linux"
  patchlevel:   "2013-12-25 revision 44422"
  full_version: "ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]"
  ```
- `hoe-3.11.0.gem`

Answer (score 1):

This is because RubyForge shutdown and [support was removed](https://github.com/seattlerb/hoe/blob/master/History.rdoc#3100--2014-03-14) from the `Hoe` gem.

If you are still having this problem, try a newer version of `net-ldap` (which as of this writing is on [0.8.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-ldap))